# Using 3 vertical dots in android for any view

Tags: android, overflow-menu

Good day i am trying to use android default 3 vertical dots icon.Meanwhile searching in the sdk resources and googling all day long i did not find any of help.Can you please tell me what does even the 3 dots at least called in android and how to use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called `more vert` and you can find it here https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_more_vert

Comment: No problem :D if you don't know about using vector assets in Android Studio check this out https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#running

Comment: i already know my whole project in vectors just could not find the default one but if i got the icon in vectors than i am happy :D haha ill accept answer in 7 minutes as stackoverflow restricts :D